# Стандартная авторизация ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Делаю сайт со стандартной авторизацией на VS 2015. 
Изначально при регистрации и логинизации используется Email.
При регистрации Я добавил поле "Имя пользователя".
При логинизации использую Email. В итоге, если Имя пользователя отлично от Email, то авторизация не происходит.

Код логинизации:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // Сбои при входе не приводят к блокированию учетной записи
        // Чтобы ошибки при вводе пароля инициировали блокирование учетной записи, замените на shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Неудачная попытка входа.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Проверил в режиме отладки, после выполнения функции **SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync** в переменную **result** попадает значение **Failure**, хотя входные данные правильные.

Код регистрации:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // Появление этого сообщения означает наличие ошибки; повторное отображение формы
        return View(model);
    }
```

Может сталкивался кто? Или знает как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score -3):

Там лажа в том что оно берет мыло или имя пользователя,но на самом деле беретвторое из етих двух

короче я  тож с этим столкнулся,оно хочет что б они совпадали

но выход есть:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        Context db = new Context();
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<User>(db));
        var userList = UserData.GetUserList();
        bool dev = !userList.Any(m => userManager.IsInRole(m.Id, "Dev") && !m.IsDel);
        ViewBag.Dev = dev;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        User user;

        try
        {
            user = db.User.Single(u => u.UserName.Equals(model.Login));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            user = null;
        }

        if (user != null && !user.IsDel)
        {
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                //case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                //    return View("Lockout");
                //case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                //    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                //case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
            //return View("Error");
        }
    }
```